# SQL Server 2008 R2: Get table_name from view from other database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two database namely `DB1` and `DB2`.

Presently working on Database `DB1`. I have a view which is stored in the database `DB2` name as `View_1`. I want get the all table names present on that view from database `DB1`.

## My Try:

I am using Database `DB1`.

**Try 1**:

```
 SELECT Table_name 
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE
 WHERE VIEW_NAME = 'DB2..View_1';
```

**Try 2**:

```
 SELECT Table_name 
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE
 WHERE VIEW_NAME = DB2..'View_1';
```

But not getting the table_name's from the other database view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this

```
 SELECT Table_name 
 FROM DB2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE
 WHERE VIEW_NAME = 'View_1';
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Will accept it within 10 min as per the SO timing constraint to accept the answer.